# What would be the negation of this statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

(∀x∈R,∃y∈R suchthat x+y=0)∧(∀x∈R,x^2 =0⇒x=0).

The LHS of the and im fine with but I dont understand how would negate statements lke this

Comment: You need De Morgan laws for the negation of a conjunction and you need the rules for negating quantifiers: $\lnot \forall$ is $\exists \lnot$ and so on.

Comment: With regards to the second statement you see in the conjunction... recall that implications of the form $P\implies Q$ can be rewritten as $\neg P \vee Q$.  This should help you to better visualize what it means to negate an implication.

Answer (score 1):

- $\neg((\forall x \in \mathbb{R} ,\exists y\in \mathbb{R} : x+y=0)\land(\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x^2 =0\implies x=0))$
- $\neg(\forall x \in \mathbb{R} ,\exists y\in \mathbb{R} : x+y=0)\lor \neg (\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x^2 =0\implies x=0)$
- $(\exists x \in \mathbb{R} : \neg(\exists y\in \mathbb{R} : x+y=0))\lor  (\exists x \in \mathbb{R} : \neg( x^2 =0\implies x=0))$
- $(\exists x \in \mathbb{R} : (\forall y\in \mathbb{R} , \neg(x+y=0)))\lor  (\exists x \in \mathbb{R} : ( x^2 =0)\land \neg( x=0)))$
- $(\exists x \in \mathbb{R} : \forall y\in \mathbb{R} , x+y\ne0)\lor  (\exists x \in \mathbb{R} :  (x^2 =0)\land (x\ne0))$